# Mathjax formatting buttons for you!

Tags: discussion, mathjax

After having to add dollar signs and format SI  units countless times in the review section on Physics, I finally got fed up and wrote a script.{*}

It basically adds buttons/keyboard shortcuts to enclose the selected text in dollar symbols and `\mathrm` SI unit formatting.

For you chemistry guys, there's an extra button that encloses stuff in `$\ce{...}$`

It's pretty useful in `/review`, and also a good shortcut when writing your own posts.

[Here's the userscript](https://stackapps.com/questions/3373/mathjax-buttons). Installation instructions are there. (also bugs/feature reqs/whatever)

<sup>*With [some urging from chem.SE.people](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38/whats-the-policy-on-systems-of-measure#comment28_39), otherwise it was going to be indefinitely in my todo list :P</sup>

Comment: any way to do it in opera?

Comment: @Ashu yep. Installn instructions for all major browsers here:http://stackapps.com/tags/script/info . Its pretty easy for opera.

Comment: @ManishEarth Could you add another button for `\begin{aligned}...\end{aligned}`, pretty please.

Comment: @Martin yes, I can. ([issue filed](https://github.com/Manishearth/Manish-Codes/issues/6) )Any suggestions for the icon? $=$?

Comment: Maybe `&=` would be appropriate, as this is the alignment char.

Comment: I might be the only one who thinks this... I noticed that the $\ce{O2}$ button will insert `$\ce{...]$` which is quite handy when you write a whole equation. It is hindering if you want to add something like `pH=-\ln[\ce{H+}]` or more complicated you will always need to clean the extra `$`. I also noticed that SI always inserts a `\:` type space, while `~` might be more appropriate, if even necessary. (Is this the right place to ask or should I go to stackapps next time.)

Comment: @Martin stackapps is better, GitHub is the best. I might change the behavior of $\ce{O2}$ later, since Alt-M ($) already inserts a pair of dollar signs. I'll change the space, too.

Answer (score 1):

### Note to users who installed it before 5/5/12 (3:51 PM UTC):

The script no longer needs to be updated (most updates include the addition of more sites/buttons and tweaks like tooltips). It auto-fetches the updates now.

I suggest you uninstall/reinstall it to run this one-time update

How to uninstall:

- Chrome: Settings>Tools>Extensions. Find the script and delete it
- Firefox: Open the GM settings and remove the script

Then re-install normally ([click here](https://github.com/Manishearth/Manish-Codes/raw/master/StackExchange/MathJaxButtons.user.js))

Comment: Does this script work with IE 11.0?

Comment: @ron never tried it, not going to, getting userscripts to run on IE is hard since there's no native support.

Answer (score 0):

It does not work. I can't figure out where does it crash but it does:
[image: controls are gone]

It also creepily installed some Auto-Review comments script I didn't ask for...
[image: my userscripts]

Comment: This is autoreviewcomments, but MathJax Buttons doesn't install it. Hm. http://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se

Comment: I'll try to fix this. Browser?

Comment: Firefox. Up to date I guess.

Comment: Well, sorry. Ihave instaled this myself and totally forgotten it.